# to limit the limit count variable to fixed value

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I want to execute some code based on value in limit count, but I want to limit its value to 20000 max.
for eg if limit count passed is 50000 then run the code three times with values as 20000,20000,10000
also if limit count is 10000 then run it as is

Comment: How did *you* calculate those three values? Do the same thing in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you need smth like that:

```
int limit = 50000;
int maxLimit = 20000;

while (limit > 0) {
  callYourCode(Math.min(limit, maxLimit));
  limit -= maxLimit;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked
  int count=50000;
  
  while(count>=20000) {
   
   System.out.println("pass 20000 to method");
   count =count-20000;
   
   
   
  }
  if(count==20000) {
   System.out.println("runnig with 20000");
  }
  else {
   System.out.println("running with "+count);
  }
this it the final code